# Defining a two-index field in FeynCalc

Tags: physics, variable-definitions, feyncalc

I'm looking to define a two-index variable $h_{\mu \nu}$ in FeynCalc but the only examples of tensors with more than one index I've seen have been constants.  Can a two-index variable be defined in FeynCalc? If so, how?

Comment: May I suggest directly contacting the developer and FeynCalc community by posting your question [on the FeynCalc forum](https://feyncalc.github.io/forum)?  You'll very likely get a response from them.

Answer (score 5):

You can define custom tensors in FeynCalc, but there is so not much you can do with them out of the box. Anyway, here is an example

```
<< FeynCalc`
DeclareFCTensor[h];
```

Contract a `h` with the metric tensor

```
h[LorentzIndex[mu], LorentzIndex[nu]] MT[mu, nu] // Contract
```

Contract a `h` with a 4-vector

Undo a contraction of `h` with a 4-vector

```
Uncontract[h[Momentum[p], Momentum[q]], p, Pair -> All]
```

[image]